# How to exit a bash loop by keyboard input?

Tags: bash, shell-script, input, for

I have a `bash lopp` as

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( c=0; c<=1000000; c++ ))
do  
SOME STUFF HERE
done
```

I interrupt the long loop by a keyboard input like `Ctrl+C` but `Ctrl+C` simply terminates the script. I am looking for an alternative to continue the current cycle and break the loop after finishing the running `STUFF` in the current cycle.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to `trap` the Control-C signal and `break` out of the `loop`, as in:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap break INT
for (( c=0; c<=1000000; c++ ))
do  
SOME STUFF HERE
done
echo "I have broken out of the interminably long for loop"
trap - INT
sleep 1
echo "END."
```

For more detail of how this works, the key lines being:

`trap break INT`

and also

`trap - INT`

We use "break" to tell trap we want to run break to break the loop when `INT` (interrupt, aka `SIGINT`) signal is generated (which happens when press Ctrl+C)

Instead of "break" we could put arbitrary shell commands in quotes, and that will be executed when the given signal (INT in our case) is generated.

Lastly we run trap again with `-` to restore the "INT" handler to the default action.

Here are some more resources for further reading and examples:

- [Linuxjournal article on bash trap command](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-trap-command) gives some more examples of using trap and nuances between the different options
- [MIT Confluence Page on traps](http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3907156) covers bash and tcsh shells
- [Beginners Guide to using "trap" to Catch Signals and Handle Errors in Shell Script](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/beginners-guide-to-using-trap-to-catch-signals-and-handle-errors-in-shell-script/) is quote extensive showing other signals sent by keyboard, as well as usage of `kill -l` to show all signals and `kill -l SIGNALNAME` to find its numeric value.